# Angularjs How do I get value of selected option ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

my script:

```
$scope.departaments = [{id: "1", name="dpt1"}, {id: "2", name="dpt2"}];
$scope.selectedDpt = $scope.departaments[0];
```

html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDpt" ng-options="dpt as dpt.name for dpt in departaments" class="form-control" id="dept.hierarchy" name="dept.hierarchy"></select>
```

and then later on at some point I want to get the selected object(or id). how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you get value by `$scope.selectedDpt` but be careful of set another value at each digest

Comment: $scope.selectedDpt always returns originally initialized value, which is $scope.departaments[0], even though it should return $scope.departaments[1]

Comment: delete $scope.selectedDpt = $scope.departaments[0]; i thinks it's setted at each digest of the app. prefer ng-init if you really want to do it

Answer (score 1):

It can be taken from `$scope.selectedDpt`, since you are binding it with `ngModel` directive. Take a look at [`select` directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Also removethis line;

```
$scope.selectedDpt = $scope.departaments[0];
```

And add this

```
ng-init="selectedDpt = departaments[0]"
```

To your `select` directive.

Comment: $scope.selectedDpt always returns originally initialized value, which is $scope.departaments[0], even though it should return $scope.departaments[1]

Comment: This is because you directly set its value with `$scope.selectedDpt = ...`. As @ThomasP1988 stated, you should use `ngInit` directive.

Comment: somethingHere should be selectedDpt?

Comment: Ops, sorry. Fixed that.

Comment: Okay weirdest thing ever. I removed that line as you said and it still didn't work. but then I changed ng-model from selectedDpt to  dept.hierarchy(same as name and id) and it worked. Then I tried ng-init="dept.hierachy=departaments[0]" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Any idea what is going on ?